# Recreate Titan Graph with Gremlin commands

Tags: titan, gremlin, gremlin-server

I'm familiar with using `graph.io(graphson()).writeGraph("/tmp/graph.json")` or `graph.io(graphml()).writeGraph("/tmp/graph.xml")` to create json or xml files which can later be used to repopulate a Titan Graph.

Is there a way to generate a series of `gremlin` graph statements in the same way that can be played back to recreate a graph?

e.g.

```
graph.addVertex(...)
graph.addEdge(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

No. There is nothing built into TinkerPop (or Titan) that will generate lines of Java code. You would have to write your own custom code to concatenate together such output.